# CDVViewController not found / Failed to import bridging header

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, cordova

XCode 7.3.1
El Captain 10.11.6
Cordova 6.3.1

I'm working at the 4:35 mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTV-tNzWxGc

When I try to build the product, I'm getting two errors under bridge-header.h;

- 'CDVViewController.h' file not found
- Failed to import bridging header '/users/jauharsa/documents/demos/swift-sd/bridge-header.h'

I've made the follow updates;

- "Yes" to Build Active Architecture Only on the project and target level
- Added the file name "bridge-header.h" to the target level of Objective-C Bridging Header
- Under the project level header search paths adding, "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/include", "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include", "$(Build_Products_Dir)" to debug, and all the ones I just stated and "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" to release.

I'm new to programming, so apologies if I'm making a dumb mistake.